# How to add a caption to a LyX table (with table numbering) using the menus?

Tags: tables, floats, lyx

I know nothing about TEX/LaTeX so I use LyX.

I created a table using the LyX menu: *Insert* > *Table...*, changed the Rows and Columns values, hit the OK button, and here it is there. However, I can't find out how to add a table numbering and caption at the bottom of it.

I would not like to get into the code.

Is it possible to do that using the menu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should first insert a float via the menus *Insert* > *Float* > *Table*:

[image]

*After* this, insert your table via the menus *Insert* > *Table...* (and specify your rows/columns):

[image]